# GCP invalid reference format when running Cloud Build

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

Hi StackOverflow peeps.

Looking for some help when trying to create a Google Cloud Platform CI/CD pipeline and getting stuck at the testing portion. I have the following Dockerfile creating images which gets triggered when I push to a github repo:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Run phase
FROM nginx
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I then have the following `cloudbuild.yaml` file building the container, pushing it to my repo, and attempting to run the yarn tests that I have:

```
# Start cloudbuild
# we just want to install and run tests for now
steps:
  # build the docker image
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    id: buildinstaller
    args:
      [
        "build",
        "-t",
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/docker-react-ci:$BRANCH_NAME-$SHORT_SHA",
        "-f",
        "Dockerfile",
        "."
      ]
  # this step pushes the image to Container Registry
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    id: Push
    args:
      - "push"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/docker-react-ci:$BRANCH_NAME-$SHORT_SHA"
  # fires the jest tests of the app so far
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: test
    args:
      - "run"
      - "-e"
      - "CI=true"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/docker-react-ci:$BRANCH_NAME-$SHORT_SHA"
      - "npm"
      - "run"
      - "test"
      - "--"
      - "--coverage"
```

The output of the Cloud Build Logs is:

```
starting build "f06de889-d88f-480d-bb51-9734cdf9447a"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://github.com/landon-sturgeon/docker-react
 * branch            3daf6a3fc0bf951b2b4de1a06d75fdeef9178e8b -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 3daf6a3 hard code the right project name  again
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "buildinstaller"
Step #0 - "buildinstaller": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0 - "buildinstaller": Sending build context to Docker daemon  921.1kB

Step #0 - "buildinstaller": Step 1/8 : FROM node:alpine as builder
< INSTALLS CONTAINER CORRECTLY REMOVED LOGS FOR BREVITY >
Step #0 - "buildinstaller": Successfully tagged gcr.io/docker-react-306100/test:latest
Finished Step #0 - "buildinstaller"
Starting Step #1 - "Push"
Step #1 - "Push": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #1 - "Push": The push refers to repository [gcr.io/docker-react-306100/test]
Step #1 - "Push": 446f1465778a: Preparing
Step #1 - "Push": 2acf82036f38: Preparing
Step #1 - "Push": 9f65d1d4c869: Preparing
Step #1 - "Push": 0f804d36244d: Preparing
Step #1 - "Push": 9b23c8e1e6f9: Preparing
Step #1 - "Push": ffd3d6313c9b: Preparing
Step #1 - "Push": 9eb82f04c782: Preparing
Step #1 - "Push": ffd3d6313c9b: Waiting
Step #1 - "Push": 9eb82f04c782: Waiting
Step #1 - "Push": 9b23c8e1e6f9: Layer already exists
Step #1 - "Push": 9f65d1d4c869: Layer already exists
Step #1 - "Push": 2acf82036f38: Layer already exists
Step #1 - "Push": 0f804d36244d: Layer already exists
Step #1 - "Push": ffd3d6313c9b: Layer already exists
Step #1 - "Push": 9eb82f04c782: Layer already exists
Step #1 - "Push": 446f1465778a: Pushed
Step #1 - "Push": latest: digest: sha256:26172522a0d7199af3e8b044f0fa73d9efed0ed278b7af16062b00060369b96a size: 1780
Finished Step #1 - "Push"
Starting Step #2 - "test"
Step #2 - "test": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #2 - "test": /usr/bin/docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
Step #2 - "test": See '/usr/bin/docker run --help'.
Finished Step #2 - "test"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 125
```

It's the `/usr/bin/docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase` error that I'm stuck on. I've tried hardcoding the repo name, but I still get the same error. Not sure what to do from here, but hoping the SO gods can come in to save the day!

Thanks!

Comment: Try "-e" "CI=true" (on separate lines)

Comment: @JohnHanley provided the right answer!

Comment: so I'm not sure what the -e adds. either way the command I added was `-e` before the CI=true on the cloudbuild yaml argument and i still get the same error

Comment: The `-e` is used to set an Env Variable at runtime of your docker image (I would suggest to study more about docker if this was unknown for you). Anyway, can you edit your question and show the new `cloudbuild.yaml` file?

Comment: Updated the `cloudbuild.yaml` with added argument @YeriPelona. So after banging my head on this problem I ended up putting the test in the `Dockerfile` as `RUN CI=true npm run test -- --coverage`. Now, if the test fails, the cloud build fails which is exactly what I wanted